# axios DELETE http request is blocked

Tags: javascript, express, http, axios

I have a react.js front end and node.js back end web application. I used mongodb as the database.

I used axios to make HTTP request from front end to back end.

I have tested my app on **localhost** when making a DELETE request and there is no problem. Below is a screenshot of my browser console of the http traffic.

[image]

Below is another screenshot of my browser console when running this web app that is deployed on a '**live environment**'(Netlify,Heroku,Mongo Atlas).

[image]

I have no clue why the HTTP DELETE request is blocked? Is this because of some sort of setting I have not configured in mongodb atlas?

Below is my javascript code on the front end which I make the axios call

```
 AxiosInstance.get("/statistics")
          .then(function (response) {
            // handle success

            let message = "";
            let sortedResultArr = [];
            sortedResultArr = response.data.sort(function (a, b) {
              return a._id - b._id;
            });
            for (let i = 0; i < sortedResultArr.length; i++) {
              message +=
                " Day " +
                sortedResultArr[i]._id +
                " Profit : " +
                sortedResultArr[i].profitPerCup.toFixed(2);
            }
            AxiosInstance.delete("/statistics").then(function () {
              alert(message);
              window.location.reload();
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
          });
```

I am wondering if this happened because I nest one axios call inside another ?

EDIT: For my backend, I use the below portion of code to handle CORS

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, "http://localhost:3001"],
  credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I also wanted to mention that I also make HTTP DELETE on different routes which worked. For my screenshots above it is `DELETE/statistics` route that is blocked. However, when the app make HTTP DELETE calls on other routes, the response is correct and the database operation is also correct.

Comment: Have you checked if its CORS policy issue?

Comment: @wk24 , I have used CORS for the backend. I have updated my question to show the portion of code I handle CORS. I also wanted to mention that I make HTTP DELETE calls on other routes of the web app and nothing faulty happens.